# Rust Box vs non-box

Tags: rust

Given a rust object, is it possible to wrap it so that multiple references and a mutable reference are allowed but do not cause problems?

For example, a `Vec` that has multiple references and a single mutable reference.

Comment: Perhaps a `RefCell`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes, but...

The type you're looking for is [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), but read on before jumping the gun!

Rust is a single-ownership language. It always will be. It's exactly that feature that makes Rust as thread-safe and memory-safe as it is. You *cannot* fully circumvent this, short of wrapping your entire program in `unsafe` and using raw pointers exclusively, and if you're going to do that, just write C since you're no longer getting any benefits out of using Rust.

So, at any given moment in your program, there must either be one thing writing to this memory or several things reading. That's the fundamental law of single-ownership. Keep that in mind; you *cannot* get around that. What I'm about to say still follows that rule.

Usually, we enforce this with our type signatures. If I take a `&T`, then I'm just an alias and won't write to it. If I take a `&mut T`, then nobody else can see what I'm doing till I forfeit that reference. That's usually good enough, and if we can, we want to do it that way, since we get guarantees at compile-time.

But it doesn't always work that way. Sometimes we can't prove that what we're doing is okay. Sometimes I've got two functions holding an, ostensibly, mutable reference, but I know, due to some other guarantees Rust doesn't know about, that only one will be writing to it at a time. Enter `RefCell`. `RefCell<T>` contains a single `T` and pretends to be immutable but lets you borrow the thing inside either mutably or immutably with `try_borrow_mut` and `try_borrow`. When we call one of these functions, we get a reference-like value that can read (and write, in the mutable case) to the original data, even though we started with a `&RefCell<T>` that doesn't *look* mutable.

But the fundamental law still holds. Note that those `try_*` functions return a `Result`, i.e. they might fail. If two functions simultaneously try to get `try_borrow_mut` references, the second one will fail, and it's your job to deal with that eventuality (even if "deal with that" means `panic!` in your particular use case). All we've done is move the single-ownership rules from compile-time to runtime. We haven't gotten rid of them; we've just changed who's responsible for enforcing them.

Comment: Also, note that if you do use `unsafe` to "get around" single ownership, your program will still be incorrect if you just circumvent the rules blindly. `unsafe` just means "I've checked this code follows the rules so the compiler doesn't have to". The compiler will still assume that the rules have been followed and outside of the `unsafe` block will use that assumption in its code generation. If all you're doing in `unsafe` is circumventing ownership rules, this will likely lead to incorrect codegen.